# Refactoring react code

Tags: reactjs

I have a class component that is a header-bar and when you click on an icon a dialog-box pop up where you can input data and save it. I am trying to split these  two items- header-bar and dialog-box into two different components. Is the best way to do this to redirect the from the header-bar component to a new dialog-box component. At the moment i have both of them in one component.Thanks for the advice.

```
    const{classes} = this.props
    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog
                open={this.state.open}
                onClose={this.handleClose}
                aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Add Folder</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                <TextField
                    margin="normal"
                    onChange={this.handleChange('name')}
                  />
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
                    Cancel
            </Button>
                <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary"
                    onChange={this.handleFieldChange}
                    value={this.state.value}>
                    Create
            </Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
            <AppBar position="static" className={classes.bar} >
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton color="inherit" aria-label="createfolder">
                        <SvgIcon>
                            <path d={createfolder}
                                onClick={this.handleClickOpen} 
                                name="firstName"/>
                        </SvgIcon>
                    </IconButton>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>

        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the best way to do this is not to redirect but same way, in a more modular or component/react way. You can create a functional component of dialog box and include it in your main component,

In the below code the functional component has been made inside the main component class itself so it can access the `this`.

```
   DialogBox = ({state}) =>(
      <Dialog
            open={state.open}
            onClose={this.handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
            <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Add Folder</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
            <TextField
                margin="normal"
                onChange={this.handleChange('name')}
              />
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
                Cancel
        </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary"
                onChange={this.handleFieldChange}
                value={state.value}>
                Create
        </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      )
```

Now include this in your header-bar component,

```
const{classes} = this.props
    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar position="static" className={classes.bar} >
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton color="inherit" aria-label="createfolder">
                        <SvgIcon>
                            <path d={createfolder}
                                onClick={this.handleClickOpen} 
                                name="firstName"/>
                        </SvgIcon>
                    </IconButton>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
           <this.DialogBox state={this.state}/>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: sorry i dont understand exactly what you are saying. Should i wrap the header-bar in a HOC because it wont allow me to use the syntax <this.DialogBox state={this.state}/>

Comment: No, you dont have to redirect or wrap again, instead you can keep the dialog as a component(answer snippet 1) and app header as a different component. And the render would look like the snippet 2 where you can see the dialog as a single component `<this.DialogBox state={this.state}/>`

Comment: i need to manage the of the Dialogbox so i cant make it a stateless component. i have to get the details from the textfield

Comment: If you meant, the open/close state, that can be managed in the state of the parent component itself. The `open` prop in <Dialog> needs just a true or false value irrespective of state or prop. And if you still want Dialog in a non stateless component you still can do it the similar way as mentioned, to import the dialog in this component itself.